# newly made topology not visible from behind

Tags: topology

so I decided to make a cape for a character and after making it, the mesh for a cape is not visible from one side
This is the same object from different angels
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In Viewport Settings, make sure Backface culling isn't checked :

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the problem